# MVC4 Razor Postback issue in Mobile website

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

can anyone tell me what are the ways to handle the postbacks in MVC4 Razor for Mobile.

I am new to MVC Development. I searched a lot but couldn't find any example that could run on my project.

Any helpful link will also be apprieciated.

---

### Code in Controller:

```
//[HttpGet]

public ActionResult TestView()
{
   return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TestView(string action,  UserSelection objSelection)
{
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(action))
   {
   }
   return View();
}
```

---

**Edit:**
In View : I have added two button with tag : Input having name=action, but different values.

When I click these button I get the "Error Loadin page" message.

Sorry: couldn't load the code due to Filter settings here.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was I created the new project and merged the code in new project & bingo It worked.

But I couldn't findout the reason for that behaviour of first project.

But anyway my project has started handling the post-backs.